# Verificar Login no Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, login

Boa tarde !
  Estou com uma dificuldade em um app que estou criando com o firebase... Seguinte, tenho a atela de login e nela tenho o botão de login com a conta do google, o que quero fazer é o seguinte, quando a pessoa selecionar a conta do google, após a autenticação quero fazer um select lá no firebase e confirmar se todos os dados de cadastro foram preenchidos, se sim, a pessoa é direcionada para a activity principal, se estiver faltando dados como escolaridade, profissão etc, significa que ele ainda não tem uma conta no realtime database, então ele é direcionado para fazer o cadastro usando o email do google... minha validação está assim, porém, abaixo pe apenas um teste, como eu estou consultando o identificador q é o ID ele já deveria constar como cadastrado pois eu consigo ver no firebase console, porém, ele cai sempre como falso na primeira vez e é levado para a tela de cadastro, assim intendo que a lógica a seguir está faltando alguma coisa:

```
if (firebase.child("USUARIOS").child(identificador).equals( usuario.getId() ) ){
                            openMainActivity();
                        } else {
                            usuario.salvar();
                            openCadastroActivity();
                        }
```

Comment: Poderia colocar como está o seu nó USUARIOS no firebase? E também como está fazendo a referencia (que acredito ser a variável firebase no seu código)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi estas tentando acessar do dados do **firebase auth**.

Sugiro que você crie no **firebase database** um nó de usuários, e grave/atualize os dados sempre que houver uma autenticação, pois a autenticação do **firebase auth** não registra os dados que estas precisando e também não lhe permite buscar informações restritas.

Exemplo:

[image: firebase]

Depois da autenticação e gravação/atualização do usuário, crie uma logica de verificação dos dados e abra a activity desejada.